# Ansible Python API connection to Cisco device

Tags: python, ansible

I use simple playbook for retrieving OSPF information from cisco router.  `ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/showrun-routers.yml -vvv` works perfectly.
I tried to run ansible-playbook from python and it's failed with such error

```
    TASK [It's time for MD5 checking on OSPF interfaces. Let's download full show run] *****  
<IP address> using connection plugin network_cli (was local) 
<IP address> starting connection from persistent connection plugin 
fatal: [IP address]: FAILED! => {"msg": "/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'ansible-connection': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n"}
```

This is output os my Python API

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from ansible.executor.playbook_executor import PlaybookExecutor
from ansible.utils.display import Display
display = Display(verbosity=7)
loader = DataLoader()

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources='/etc/ansible/hosts')
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
playbook_path = '/etc/ansible/showrun-routers.yml'

if not os.path.exists(playbook_path):
    print '[INFO] The playbook does not exist'
    sys.exit()

Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'become', 'become_method', 'become_user', 'verbosity', 'check','diff'])
options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='local', module_path='/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible', forks=100, remote_user=None, private_key_file=None, ssh_common_args='', ssh_extra_args='', sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None, verbosity=True, check=False, diff=False)

variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
passwords = {}

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=passwords)

results = pbex.run()
```

I tried to compare verbose output from ansible-playbook and python script and they both use network_cli module
**ANSIBLE-PLAYBOOK OUTPUT**

```
    TASK [It's time for MD5 checking on OSPF interfaces. Let's download full show run] ******   
task path: /etc/ansible/showrun-routers.yml:19 
<IP address> using connection plugin network_cli (was local)   
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_command.py 
<omited>
```

**Python API OUTPUT**
was mentioned at the top of my question. 
So I cannot understand what actually python means when raise the error can't open file 'ansible-connection'. Do you have some suggestion regarding this error?..
Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a symlink to ansible-connection file
/etc/ansibleinpython#ansible-connection -> /usr/bin/ansible-connection